# Can we specify two different partitions for dfs.data.dir in CDH4?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

As CDH4 follows JBOD pattern of creating a directory from 1 to n for n nodes.
Can I have two directories with same name in two different partitions for data dir.
I have /mnt/disk1 and /mnt/disk2 partitions each of 100GB and I wanna use them both for HDFS.
Will the following conf work

```
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/mnt/disk1/1/dfs/dn,mnt/disk2/1/dfs/dn,mnt/disk1/2/dfs/dn,mnt/disk2/2/dfs/dn</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As far as the configuration goes it simply sees these as different directories. You will have more efficiency if each one is a different device because that will help against IO bounds.

Comment: Ok. So you're saying this will work. Thanks!! I'll just give it a shot and will accept the answer..:)

Comment: Just to be certain, each disk has two partitions right? So it's something like sdb1 => /mnt/disk1/1/dfs/dn, sdb2 => /mnt/disk1/2/dfs/dn, sdc1 => /mnt/disk2/1/dfs/dn, sdc2 => /mnt/disk2/2/dfs/dn? If each disk only has one partition then you may have trouble. If it's mounted like I've shown you're fine, but I'm not sure the extra partitions give any efficiency.